# angular 7 router navigate cannot match

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router, angular9

I defined a router module

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'general', component: MapComponent},
  {path: 'general/:id', component: MapComponent},
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent}
])
```

Later I created a map that is `Leaflet` map. When I click the map I want to redirect to chield path with `route.navigate`.

```
this.router.navigate(['./germany'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

First click is working and navigate is redirect to chield path. After second click I get an error is

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'general/germany/germany'

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this without dot

```
this.router.navigate(['/germany'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

or this

```
this.router.navigate(['/germany']);
```

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['general/germany']);` will working. However you have two ways for hidden map:

1) You create two different components and in general component you show map , after click you redirect to country component and in this component you parse route url an show info for country.
2) Otherwise you can use `router-outlet`

Answer (score 0):

A simple `this.router.navigate(['general/germany'])` should work.

Comment: it is working but there is a problem. The problem is map component is loading again.

Comment: Your router module has this line - `{path: 'general/:id', component: MapComponent},`
Change the MapComponent to your desired component.

Comment: My project have two parts. The first part is map and second part is table. In a page left side is map right side is table. The map shouldn't load again.

Comment: when I use your method MapComponent is loading again

Comment: the route is working perfectly. The problem is with how you have configured your routes in the routing module. what component do you want to display in the route `general/germany`?

Comment: If you check your code, you have mentioned like this in the routing module - `RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'general', component: MapComponent},
  {path: 'general/:id', component: MapComponent},
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent}
])`
You can see that you have configured your `general/:id` route to load the `MapComponent`. You need to change the `MapComponent` and write the desired component you wish to load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216328/discussion-between-harish-and-hermes).

Comment: I createad a stack you can reach here https://angular-leaflet-routing.stackblitz.io